# Error 500 en Ubuntu Server 18.04 al ejecutar el .htaccess (url amigables)

Tags: php, ubuntu, .htaccess

Tengo configurado mi .htaccess con las siguientes lineas

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

Pero al intentar accedes a las url amigables me marca error 404 
Eso solo sucede en Ubuntu Server 18.04 con apache2 y php7.2, lo he ejecutado desde XAMPP y otros servidores y funciona a la perfeccion.
La siguiente url es un ejemplo.

**ip_servidor/apidata/usuario**

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que no has activado el modulo mod_rewrite para el caso en Ubuntu puedes correr el siguiente comando.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
systemctl restart apache2
```

Luego tienes que habilitar el AllowOverride

```
<Directory /home/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

El archivo lo puedes encontrar en /etc/apache2/apache2.conf luego reinicia el apache nuevamente y intentas nuevamente, ahora si con esto no solucionas el problema puedes enviar el log del apache que esta en /var/log/apache2/error.log